# use Qt5 udp multicast or boardcast, can`t send muiltcast msg to the network, may be is listen

Tags: c++, qt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05kM6.png)

this is the code, start two process in one pc, but these process can`t communicate.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHostInfo>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboTargetIp->addItem("224.0.1.0", "224.0.1.0");
    ui->comboTargetIp->addItem("224.0.1.10", "224.0.1.10");
    ui->comboTargetIp->addItem("224.0.2.10", "224.0.2.10");
    ui->comboTargetIp->addItem("224.0.3.10", "224.0.3.10");
    ui->comboTargetIp->addItem("255.255.255.255", "255.255.255.255");
    LabSocketState = ui->label_3;
    ui->statusBar->addWidget(LabSocketState);
    QString localIP = getLocalIp();//获取IP地址
    this->setWindowTitle(this->windowTitle()+"---本机IP"+localIP);
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket;
    udpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::MulticastTtlOption,1);//对socket进行参数设置
    connect(udpSocket,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),this,SLOT(onSocketStateChange(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
    onSocketStateChange(udpSocket->state());
    connect(udpSocket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onSocketReadyRead()));
}

void MainWindow::on_bindBtn_clicked()
{//加入组播
    QString IP = ui->comboTargetIp->currentText();
    groupAddress = QHostAddress(IP);
    quint16 groupPort = ui->spinBox->value();//端口
    if(udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4,groupPort,QUdpSocket::ShareAddress))
    {
        //udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress);//加入多播组
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("**加入组播成功");
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("组播地址IP: "+IP);
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("**绑定端口："+QString::number(groupPort));
        ui->bindBtn->setEnabled(false);
        ui->stopBtn->setEnabled(true);
        ui->comboTargetIp->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("**绑定端口失败");
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_stopBtn_clicked()
{//退出组播
    udpSocket->leaveMulticastGroup(groupAddress);//退出组播
    udpSocket->abort();
    ui->bindBtn->setEnabled(true);
    ui->stopBtn->setEnabled(false);
    ui->comboTargetIp->setEnabled(true);
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("**已退出组播，解除端口绑定");
}

void MainWindow::on_btnSend_clicked()
{//发送组播消息
    quint16 groupPort = ui->spinBox->value();
    QString msg = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QByteArray array;
    array = msg.toUtf8();
    udpSocket->writeDatagram(array,groupAddress,groupPort);
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("[multicst]"+msg);
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
    ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
}

void MainWindow::on_clearBtn_clicked()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_quitBtn_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}
void MainWindow::onSocketReadyRead()
{//读取数据报
    QByteArray datagram;
    datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
    QHostAddress peerAddr;
    quint16 peerPort;
    udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size(),&peerAddr,&peerPort);
    QString str =datagram.data();
    QString peerStr = "[From"+peerAddr.toString()+":"+QString::number(peerPort)+"]";
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(peerStr);
}
QString MainWindow::getLocalIp()
{//获取本机IP
    QString hostName = QHostInfo::localHostName();//本机主机名
    QHostInfo hostInfo = QHostInfo::fromName(hostName);
    QString localIP = " ";
    QList<QHostAddress> addList = hostInfo.addresses();
    if(!addList.isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<addList.count();++i)
        {
            QHostAddress aHost = addList.at(i);
            if(QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol == aHost.protocol())
            {
                localIP = aHost.toString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //localIP = "0.0.0.0";
    return localIP;
}
```

screenshot is the boardcast, use the 255.255.255.255 send msg.
multicast and boardcast listen and recivce maybe not same.
target is use multicast and boardcast discover other device.
use qt network to send and recvice the msg, but the wireshark catched msg type is not boardcast.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX8uu.png)

qtcreator has broadcast sender and reciver demo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).